# JQuery adding error message to a table if there is no data to be submitted when submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a program that gets details from a user then when the user clicks submit the details are sent to a database and returns information.  If there is there nothing to return, such as there is no person that they are searching for then I want an error message to be posted in the table that the search results would have been posted in.

Comment: Sounds great, please post the code you've tried.

Comment: post code, or we can't help.  We aren't here to write an app for you.  We are here to review code you've written and help you debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
      if(noresults found){   

           $('#myTable').empty()
           var newRow = $("<tr><td>no results found</td></tr>");
           $("#myTable").append(newRow);

       } else {

           //proceed with your logic

       }
```